# how to fix google chrome always open localhost

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu-17.04

Each time I open (some link, shortcut) chrome opens the path [http://localhost:8080/**karma**/?id=68816665](http://localhost:8080/__karma__/?id=68816665), and it is renamed Karma - Google Chrome, I am using ubuntu, how can I solve this?

Comment: No idea what your problem is. Whatever it is, sounds pretty offtopic anyway. Pleas read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: this error was caused by a tool to test my app, and I think it is valid but if it is not valid remove it

Comment: @ÁngelOrtizOlivera It sounds like your problem was very localized.  If you could edit your question to provide more details about your configuration, this question could become useful by you posting an answer to your own question below with details about what happened and how you fixed it.  Be as detailed as possible.

Comment: @zero298 My problem was:
when I started using Karma to do my e2e tests my Chrome browser always opened localhost: 8080 ... with open any link or I directly open the browser. Delete and re-installed chrome but did not work, then check the files of shortcuts and this had been modified by karma. modify them and everything works fine, I just solved it

Comment: @zero298 do you thing this questions should be deleted or i leave it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fix this:

Check if your file chrome.desktop have karma argument configurations in

~/.local/share/applicaitons

```
cd ~/.local/share/applications
rm chrome.desktop
```